# Partition deleted, but my comp see it

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning

My win xp sp3 was infected and I installed another instance of OS on D partition, to save my files.
I finished the job, reinstall OS on the first partition, and delete D partition (partition magic).
But still, when I starting Windows, my comp ask me (on starting DOS screen) which Win I want to run - the first or the second one, although the second one does not exist.
How can I solve this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Click *Start*, choose *Run* and type **msconfig**. Click the second tab (*Boot*) and delete the entry of an old Windows installation (on partition D:) like shown on [this](http://mythoughtsonit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/clip_image002.jpg) sample picture.

Answer (score 2):

Please Google

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-delete-modify-or-disable-an-incorrect-or-duplicate-entry-on-the-xp-boot-menu/

Check here you can find the answer